# Select a random (ish) element in an abseil::node_hash_map?

Tags: c++, performance, hash, hashmap, abseil

Is it possible to select efficiently a somewhat random element in `abseil::node_hash_map`, or more generally any `abseil` map?

For example, I'd be happy with an approach that selected a slot at random, then found the next occupied slot and chose a random element from within the elements hashed to that slot, but it isn't clear this is possible without access to the map internals.

Something like `std::next(map, n)` where `n` is an integer selected randomly between `[0, map.size())` would work but is very slow with complexity `O(map.size())`.

Comment: If you are selecting a lot of random elements it may be worth caching the keys in a vector and selecting a random key from the vector each time?

Comment: @Galik - it's hard to keep the vector in sync with the map efficiently, e.g, deleting elements leaves a hole in the vector: erasing it is O(n), etc.

Comment: This won't be clean at all (or safe from code updates) but the [internals of abseil::node_hash_map](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/container/internal/raw_hash_set.h) would allow you to select [a group](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/container/internal/raw_hash_set.h) and find the first [valid byte](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/container/internal/raw_hash_set.h#L260). They allocate the control bytes in a contiguous array so it has O(1) access (and relatively efficient search with ```SSE2``` and ```AVX```).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.

The closest you can get, is to create a separate array of pointers to node_hash_map elements, and then select randomly among those pointers.  That way, the very first time you choose an element, it's O(N) time, but after that it's O(1).

Comment: Thanks. Only O(1) until the next mutation of the map, I suppose (unless you try to keep this array in sync with the map as mutations occur).